# Aqui o problema é a pergunta ou a resposta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Apareceu-me a resposta a esta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56295/somando-coluna-com-jquery (VER IMAGEM) para analise de **Primeiras publicações** e eu não sei se o problema é da pergunta, da resposta ou de nenhuma das duas...

A pergunta parece um pouco subjetiva, mas ao ver o exemplo dá para ter uma noção do que o AP precisa.

A resposta está de acordo com a pergunta. Assim meio vaga.

O que acham da pergunta? Da resposta? Existe algum problema nelas?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: A pergunta já foi removida.

Comment: @rray fica a imagem, que acho que a discussão se pode manter.

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida porque tanto a pergunta como a resposta para mim me parecem percetíveis, embora muito resumidas...

Comment: Não entendi porque ele excluiu, só perguntei qual era a dúvida (que no caso não foi perguntado nada).

Comment: @renan dá para ver que ele quer saber como fazer isso. o AR disse como fazer, mas duma forma meia resumida... Deixa ver o que diz o pessoal sobre isso...

Comment: Só faltou jogar o código do jsifddle na pergunta, não precisava remover ela.

Comment: Eu penso que, se não for para ter uma pergunta (o mínimo), então que pelo menos tenha mais detalhes. É melhor do que responder algo subjetivo, deduzindo o que o AP precisa. Posteriormente tornam-se uma daquelas "perguntas camaleão". Só achei estranho a exclusão da pergunta mesmo, mas ok.

Comment: @renan então se a perguntas estivesse: "Como posso fazer a soma de minha coluna usando jQuery , a cada inserção que faço na tabela, o total tem que somar?"

Comment: Achei curioso o uso das tarjas pretas ultimamente. É como colocar uma foto do Michael Jackson com tarja nos olhos para não identificar quem é potencial pedófilo :D

Comment: @bigown se o AP decidiu apagar a pergunta quem sou eu para colocar os dados dele ali né? Sempre usei as ditas :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O SOpt está cheio de perguntas sem jeito que originam respostas ainda piores.

Pessoalmente não vejo como uma pergunta destas pode receber uma resposta decente, muito menos que venha a ajudar mais alguém no futuro. É como estar a fazer um dicionário para  uma língua falada por 1 pessoa no mundo inteiro.

#### A Pergunta

Na pergunta não temos uma apresentação do problema, apenas um cenário que vai dar origem a opiniões, porque para lidar com o problema da forma como o mesmo se encontra exposto, cada um vai ter a sua solução.

Por vezes penso que quem coloca algumas perguntas não quer ser ajudado:

[image: Cartoon]

<sup>Source: https://steenschledermann.wordpress.com/category/ambition-2/</sup>

#### A resposta

A resposta, naturalmente, segue a mesma filosofia da pergunta, sem código, sem instrução, faculta uma solução válida para o exposto na pergunta, embora na forma de diálogo.

---

Expostos os factos, e referente ao perguntado, o problema nasceu na pergunta, pois se a mesma estivesse a apresentar um problema especifico a ser resolvido, não obteria respostas como a que foi colocada.

**Nota:**
Não vejo motivo para ["faixas pretas"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2576/aqui-o-problema-%C3%A9-a-pergunta-ou-a-resposta#comment8901_2576) em assuntos a serem discutidos no META sobre o site, o site é publico e a informação presente no mesmo de igual forma publica. Todos podem ver, aceder, etc.
Defendo sim total transparência, mas claro, está no direito de cada um proceder da forma que entende ser a mais adequada e o respeito pela privacidade alheia tem o seu valor!

Comment: Zuul concordo com tudo o que disseste. Mas como o AP resolveu apagar a pergunta achei por bem colocar as faixas. E neste caso a pergunta deixa de ser publica e só quem tem reputação a pode ver.

Comment: @JorgeB. E agiste muito bem :)